# How to hide other input when one is checked?

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<div>
    Group 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="B">A<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="I">B<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="A">C<br>
</div>
<div>
    Group 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="testing2" value="B">A<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="testing2" value="I">B<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="testing2" value="A">C<br>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        var checkname = $(this).attr("name");
        $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").removeAttr("checked");
        this.checked = true;
    }
});
```

This script make in sort that checkbox act like radio so only 1 can be checked for the same name attribute. Now I want it to hide those who are unchecked with the same name attribute. And if I uncheck the checked one, all other checkbox comes back.

A fiddle you say ? : http://jsfiddle.net/warface/gcX7Y/

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you don't want to use radio buttons for this purpose?

Comment: Yes because I want this to be un-checkable ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/P2d4R/3/

I edited your HTML as well to wrap checkboxes in `label` tags, which makes it simpler to hide.

```
<div>Group 1
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="B">A</label>
    <br />
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="I">B</label>
    <br />
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="A">C</label>
    <br />
</div>


$("input:checkbox").change(function () {
    var checkname = $(this).attr("name");
    if (this.checked) {
        $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").not(this)
            .removeAttr("checked")
            .parent()
            .hide();
    } else {
        $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").parent().show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice but the checkboxes don't comes back when unchecked

Comment: On the same question, how to check initial if a checkbox is already check so it could run this script and hide those not checked in the same group above on window load ?

Comment: Separate inside of the `change` handler into a function, say `showHideCheckboxes(checkbox)`, then call it when document loads and pass any checked checkboxes.

Comment: Did you replace `this` with parameter name `checkbox` in your separated function `showHideCheckboxes()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your function to:

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        var checkname = $(this).attr("name");
        $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").removeAttr("checked");
        this.checked = true;
        $(this).siblings(':checkbox').hide();
    } else {
        $(this).siblings(':checkbox').show();   
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqZKu/4/)

This will leave the `br` elements, however this will also leave the letters, if you want to hide those as well, it'd be a good idea to wrap them in a `span` or `label` element or something similar, and the function would need a little change, if you're OK with the letters showing, this should be OK...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function() {
    var checkname = $(this).attr("name");
    if (this.checked) {
        $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").not(this).hide().removeAttr("checked");
    } else {
        $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").show();
    }
});
```